# How to use BQL inside Bloomberg BQUANT function?

Tags: python, sql, bloomberg

Is there any documentation available for the recent bloomberg function BQNT? I know they are using bql and I found a few websites with some source codes but not enough to actually learn all the possibilities. Does anyone know where to find any documentation? or how the code would look like to import graph data from the terminal?

I've managed to find a document for excel's BQL function but not much further than that.

A few lines of bqnt bql code:
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/35346295

excel function:
http://fintools.com/BQL/Introduction_to_BQL_for_Excel%20080718_f%20jb.pdf

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is available into BQNT application. You can open projects regarding fixed and variable investment.

Note: Despite PYTHON allow to use objects to access information you can use the same BQL created in EXCEL into BQNT server.

Educational sample: How read BQL into BQNT server.

```
import bql
bq = bql.Service()

cmd = "get( PX_LAST() ) for( members('ESGUSO Index') )"
response = bq.execute(cmd)

df = response[0].df();
```